# login from cygwin to Mac OS X using xterm issue

Tags: macos, cygwin, xterm

- open cygwin shell
- run `ssh -Y user@MACOSXSERVER`

  - `No xauth data using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding` <-- Warning
  - `login MACOSXSERVER OK`
- `set DISPLAY=CYGWINIP:0.0`
- xterm &

And I get the following error

- Xlib: connection to "CYGWINIP:0.0" refused by server Xlib: No protocol specified

What went wrong?

Comment: It should be moved to superuser.

Comment: @paul: Don't add [not-programming-related] tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not

Comment: @Roger: sorry - I was still a n00b back in Feb. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running xhost + before run ssh solves this problem.

Comment: It also allows absolutely anyone to connect to your X server, which is a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You're rewriting the value of `$DISPLAY` as set by `sshd`. This is preventing X forwarding from working. Stop doing this.